# How can I use msgid during Android strings localization?

Tags: android, localization

In Android sources I see such strings:

```
<string name="app_name" msgid="8095131950334945205">"Calculadora"</string>
```

Notice the 'msgid', this indicates existence of some tool to manage strings translation. What the tool is it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can assume that it implies the existence of some tool.  But there are other explanations as to the reason for the msgid attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743058/whats-the-meaning-of-attribute-msgid-in-strings-xml and http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/04/08/android2po-managing-android-translations/ ... Some people seem to think it means that Android uses something internally to manage translations, but there's no indication from what I can see that Google's internal tool is publicly available.

Answer (score 4):

This msgid comes when used with tools like a2po to create po files and then they are used to translate the strings automatically using tools like [poedit](http://poedit.net/). You can easily ignore the **msgid** property and update the translation manually. Here is the link for [android2po](https://github.com/miracle2k/android2po).
[Here](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/04/08/android2po-managing-android-translations/) is another reference for translation.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably Motodev Studio:
http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio

Check out its features:
http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/features

It is possible to use Google Translate inside Motodev Studio to automatically translate all your strings.