# What's the meaning of attribute 'msgid' in strings.xml?

Tags: android

What's the meaning of attribute 'msgid' in strings.xml ?

How to get its value?

Comment: there is no "msgid" related to `strings.xml`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Comment: I think, you are using a localized string file.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute "msgid" is present in strings.xml if you are using string localization. For example, if you have alternate application strings for Spanish in the folder values-es, values.xml will contain "msgid".

When I look at the strings.xml for Spanish I see some long values like

8340973892742019101

What is interesting is that strings.xml for Italian and other languages contains the same msgid for the same string.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that it are some unique resource IDs, produced internally by the application. So, I do not think it makes sense to search for additional meaning in them. They are unique within the application, and that is only important.

Comment: Do not understand why they could be useful for you. But, one trick is to take strings.xml from non-default language, copy it to raw/assets dir and make a build with it. Then read it programatically from raw/assets and use xml parser to extract the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

These are operating system's strings and come from the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` package. You can see them defined [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/febed84a3a3cb7c2cb80d580d79c31e22e9643a5/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res)