# How do I change the text shown in GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging, android-dialog

I am trying to follow the gcm tutorial from Googles docs. They say to call this method if Play Services are out of date:

```
 GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity, 9000).show();
```

That's fine, but it puts a dialog that says "This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services" with an "Update" button. I want to change the title and the message text. My users CAN skip the update, and the app will still run. They just won't get push notifications. How do I change the message of the dialog?

I would like to do something like:

```
Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity, 9000);
errorDialog.setTitle("out of date");
errorDialog.setMessage("Please update or push notifications won't work. Thank you");
errorDialog.show();
```

Comment: Try my answer. It should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override desired string value in your application's `strings.xml` like this. Simply add these lines in your `strings.xml`

For message on dialog

```
<string name="common_google_play_services_update_text" msgid="448354684997260580">This app won\'t run unless you update Google Play services.</string>
```

For title on dialog

```
<string name="common_google_play_services_update_title" msgid="6006316683626838685">out of date</string>
```

**EDIT**
You could find more information here
http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2010/04/08/android2po-managing-android-translations/
and [What's the meaning of attribute 'msgid' in strings.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743058/whats-the-meaning-of-attribute-msgid-in-strings-xml/4764749#4764749)

`msgid` is used in android internal strings for localization but I never found any documentation about it. Two reference I have as above. I believe if you remove the `msgid` still it would work, although I never tried it.

The source of this code is

```
android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_strings.xml
```

Comment: That worked! Why and how? Wha'ts the purpose of msgid="" in both of those strings? Can you link me to the docs or source code of this? Thanks!