# Google Cloud Messaging alert message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Cloud Messaging alert message and want to change their apiAvailability.getErrorDialog message to my own language.  How can I change it?

```
if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
...
```

Comment: Is it not changing the language based on the settings of your phone?

Comment: Because my app is only one language so it does not matter which language is set in their phone, I still want to show my language.  Also, their alert wordings is not good, so I want to edit the wordings.

Comment: You can try this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200416/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-dialog-in-android)